# How to call web services in android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, unit-testing, tree

My teammate has developed an application in `Asp.NET` and also wrote Web services in it. My supervisor told me to call these services from Android. I have searched extensively on Google, but I am unable to understand how to call Web Services from Android.

Asp.Net Web services are:

"GenerateTreeFromXMLWebService.asmx" web service class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace UnitTestWebApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for GenerateTreeFromXMLWebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class GenerateTreeFromXMLWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        Node node = new Node();

        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        string xml;   //to save the xml data value

        // this method is for reading xml from file and storing it in a string
        public GenerateTreeFromXMLWebService()
        {
            xml = File.ReadAllText("E:\\Unit Testing\\AdWordsTestsnew.xml");
            xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        //this method is used to separate parent nodes with their child from xml file
        [WebMethod]
        public Node generateXMLTree()
        {

            XElement rootElement = xDoc.Element("Node");



            node.ResultName = rootElement.Attribute("result").Value;
            node.MethodName = rootElement.Attribute("name").Value;

            if (rootElement.HasElements)
                generateChild(node, rootElement);

            return node;

        }
        //this method is used for making child nodes
        void generateChild(Node node, XElement rootElement)
        {

            foreach (XElement a in rootElement.Elements("Node"))
            {
                Node K = new Node();
                K.ResultName = a.Attribute("result").Value;
                K.MethodName = a.Attribute("name").Value;

                node.AddChild(K);
                //this recursion is for making inner child node of the child functions
                generateChild(K, a);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Service.cs class:

```
namespace GenerateTree
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call these services? Any tutorial links will be appreciated.

Comment: Before posting a question you have to dig some documents, did you?

Comment: Yes I have.
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr  
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

and other documents but not understand what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is .net soap-web-service then this url help you.

http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/2012/05/28/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android-only-soap-service-not-rest-service/

Thanks.